# How do i do unit testing on a python class with a constructor?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I am new to Pytest and i wanted to do unit testing, but it fails saying the class has a constructor.
file app.py:

```
class SQLService:
    def __init__(self):
        self.db_engine = create_engine(db_string, connect_args={'options': '-csearch_path={}'.format("schema_name")}, echo=False)
        base = declarative_base()
        session = sessionmaker(self.db_engine)
        self.session = session()
        base.metadata.create_all(self.db_engine)

    def insert_row(self, name, project_name):
        table = MyTable(
        Name=name, 
        Project=project_name, 
        )

        self.session.add(table)
        self.session.commit()
```

Same for this db_class.py:

```
class MyTable(base):
    __tablename__ = "table_name"
    Name = Column(String)
    Project = Column(String)
```

Errors:

> PytestCollectionWarning: cannot collect test class 'SQLService'
> because it has a __init_constructor (from app.py)
>
> PytestCollectionWarning: cannot collect test class 'String' because it
> has a __init__constructor ( from: db_class.py)

Is there a way around this or a different tool that i can use?

Thank you

Comment: Please update your question with the code that has a constructor.

Comment: and now please update your question with the error message about the constructor.

Comment: How are you running `pytest`? Normally you would point it at the `.py` file(s) containing your _tests_, but I suspect you're pointing it at the `.py` file(s) containing the implementations to be tested. By default, pytest will run all files of the form `test_*.py` or `*_test.py` in the current directory and its subdirectories.

Comment: Hi, i made an .ini file and pointed to test all functions and classes and i go to the directory and use the command pytest. Did this because the code base is a lot bigger than what i wrote in the example. Used *.py for files and * for classes and functions.

Comment: In pytest a test class should not have a constructor. Can you post the directory layout of your test code and the way you run pytest on CLI?